# Creating NSError * results in application crash

Tags: objective-c, crash, nserror

I have the following situation:

My domain class gets some input validates it, and if validation passes it proceeds with saving data.
When control flow reaches the if statements, the application crashes

```
- (BOOL)createGmailAccountWithName:(NSString *)name
                                 email:(NSString *)email
                           andPassword:(NSString *)password
                                 error: (NSError **) error {
  if (!name || name.length == 0) {
    *error = [self createError:@"name"];
    return NO;
  }

  if (!email || email.length == 0) {
    *error = [self createError:@"email"];
    return NO;
  }

  if (!password || password.length == 0) {
    *error = [self createError:@"password"];
    return NO;
  }

  //..
}


-(NSError *) createError: (NSString *) field {

  NSString *errorMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Property %@ is required", field];

  NSDictionary *userInfo = @{
    NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey: NSLocalizedString(errorMessage, nil)
  };

  NSError *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:ACCOUNT_STORE_ERROR_DOMAIN
  code:-1
  userInfo:userInfo];

  return error;
}
```

When I comment out all lines where the validation happens, the application does not crash. 
I have no idea why this is happening. Can anyone point me into the right direction?

Comment: Are you sure the createGmail method is being called with an error object? You'd crash if it were called with NULL. You should check that error != NULL before dereferencing it.

Comment: They're not called with an error object. Actually I just want to pass in a NULLed pointer which points to an error object when validation fails

Comment: Ok, see if the answer I posted addresses this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have this method:

```
- (BOOL)createGmailAccountWithName:(NSString *)name
                             email:(NSString *)email
                       andPassword:(NSString *)password
                             error: (NSError **) error
```

Folks are probably going to call it either like this:

```
NSError *error;
[accountCreator createGmailAccountWithName:@"Ben" 
                                     email:@"foo@example.com" 
                               andPassword:@"pwd"
                                     error:&error];
if (error)
{
    NSLog(@"Hey I got an error: %@", error);
}
```

Or like this:

```
[accountCreator createGmailAccountWithName:@"Ben"
                                     email:@"foo@example.com"
                               andPassword:@"pwd"
                                     error:NULL];
// I couldn't care less about an error
```

In the second case, your code will will try to dereference `**error`, `*error` is not a valid pointer and would cause a crash.

Comment: It should be noted that Cocoa convention is to use the direct return value -- not `if(error)` -- to determine whether a valid error object has been passed back.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Agreed, though you'll see the convention bucked even in Cocoa itself.